# Dictionary matching with wilcard word?

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have a python dictionary as follows:

```
myDict = {"I need you to call the doctor please.":
            "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that."}
```

However, if I have a variable called `myName` that is set equal to `"XYZ"` I want it to just output:

```
"I'm sorry, XYZ. I'm afraid I can't do that."
```

I am curious how to set up the dictionary values then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

However you did it, you would have to do something extra to your value after you extract it from the dictionary.

You could store a format string as your value:

```
name = 'Dave'
myDict = {
    'I need you to call the doctor please.':
        "I'm sorry, {name}. I'm afraid I can't do that."
}
```

You would pass the formatting parameters to `str.format` once you extracted the value:

```
myDict['I need you to call the doctor please.'].format(name=name)
```

You could also use old-style formats:

```
"I'm sorry, %(name). I'm afraid I can't do that." % {'name':
```

name}

Unnamed parameters would work too:

```
"I'm sorry, {}. I'm afraid I can't do that.".format(name)
"I'm sorry, %s. I'm afraid I can't do that." % name
```

Comment: awesome any way to do the same for keys?

Comment: @user1357015. Not nearly as easily. You should ask a separate question for that.

Comment: @user1357015. Selecting the answer that works best for you is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the name occurs only once in the dictionary value

```
myDict = {"I need you to call the doctor please.": "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that."}
name = "Dave"
myName = "XYZ"

myDict["I need you to call the doctor please."].replace(name, myName)
```

Output

```
"I'm sorry, XYZ. I'm afraid I can't do that."
```

To make it generic for `n` names

```
myDict = {
           "I need you to call the doctor please.": "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that.",
           "I want you to call the Mad Physicist please.": "I'm sorry, Mad Physicist. I'm afraid I can't do that."
         } 

names = ["Dave", "Mad Physicist"]
replacement = ["XYZ", "Van Peer"]
i=0

for x in myDict:
    myDict[x] = myDict[x].replace(names[i],replacement[i])
    i+=1

print(myDict)
```

Output

```
{
  'I need you to call the doctor please.': "I'm sorry, XYZ. I'm afraid I can't do that.", 
  'I want you to call the Mad Physicist please.': "I'm sorry, Van Peer. I'm afraid I can't do that."
}
```

Comment: What if the value contains "Dave" in multiple contexts, and you only want to replace some of them?

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks, I understand the limitation with `replace` in such situations. I thought the input was to remain as it is.

Comment: You should always assume that OP is giving a minimal example that exemplifies the *type* of issue they are dealing with, not necessarily the exact problem, especially with something as generic as this.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks, will follow this going forward! `replace` is not the ideal solution here, still tried to make it generic, with one assumption.

Answer (score 0):

```
def name():
    name = raw_input("What is your name: ")
    myDict = {"I need you to call the doctor please.": "I'm sorry, " + name + ". I'm afraid I can't do that."}
    print myDict
```

This is how you would do it.

Comment: What if you want to use the same dictionary for multiple names?

Comment: Then if you want the name to choose at random you can have it like this.

Comment: def name():
love = random.choice(name)                                                                                                            
name = ['name','name','name'] 
myDict = {"I need you to call the doctor please.": "I'm sorry, " + love + ". I'm afraid I can't do that."}
print myDict

Comment: I think you missed the point of my question. What if you want to have one version of `myDict` laying around, but HAL or whatever is talking to both Dave and Susan? Or are you suggesting a separate version of myDict for each person?

Comment: Your code's indentation is incorrect and you would need to use `name()` in the key's value definition.